# C - MPI - Bsend no work with buffer attach

Tags: c, mpi

I want the buffer to be full before I start receiving. It gives me the feeling that the buffer size is less than necessary

I followed the documentation to the letter but I can't see the error
https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Buffer_attach.html

In some cases it gives me the feeling that with a specific buffer size I can perform more bsend than theoretically allowed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
   int rank, size, tag=0;
   MPI_Status status;
   MPI_Request request;
   int flag;
   
   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

   int bsends_totales=1000000;
   if (rank!=0) //Nodos esclavos
      {
      int size_bsend;
      MPI_Pack_size( 1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size_bsend );
     
      int size_buffer=bsends_totales*(size_bsend+MPI_BSEND_OVERHEAD);
      int * buffer = malloc(size_buffer);
      memset(buffer,0,size_buffer);
      MPI_Buffer_attach(buffer,size_buffer); //Buffer saliente
     
      int enviar=4;
      int sends_realizados=0;
      for (int i=0;i<bsends_totales;i++)
        {
        printf("BSENDS realizados... %d\n",sends_realizados);
        MPI_Bsend(&enviar,1,MPI_INT,0,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        sends_realizados=sends_realizados+1;
        }
      printf("BSENDS TOTALES REALIZADOS: %d\n",sends_realizados);

      MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Buffer_detach(&buffer,&size_buffer);
      free(buffer);
      printf("TERMINE\n");
      }
   else //Master
      {
      int recibido;
      
      MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      for (int i=0;i<bsends_totales;i++)
         {
         MPI_Recv(&recibido,1,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
         }
      
      }
   
   MPI_Finalize();
   return 0;
   }
```

Before being able to fill the buffer an error appears

```
OUTPUT:
BSENDS realizados... 119696
BSENDS realizados... 119697
BSENDS realizados... 119698
BSENDS realizados... 119699
BSENDS realizados... 119700
code exit 11
```

Comment: The attached buffer needs to be large enough for all communication that will be simultaneously active. You are doing a bunch of sends that may overlap because of eager sends, so the buffer size probably needs to be big enough for all those sends, rather than just for one.

Comment: How would it be for this example?

Comment: at first glance, the buffer is large enough. which process is crashing? the sender or the receiver? have you tried an other MPI library? (for example, if you are using Open MPI, try MPICH or one of its derivative)